How can I implement row-count in DataTables when the results are paginated?
I use DataTables to paginate and order a table containing user data.
The full data set comes from a MySQL database via a .NET application.
The first column of the table has to contain the (current) row count in a manner that would make the count "immune" to rearranging the rows (sorting, in other words). This is why I have used a CSS-based row count, as visible below:


new DataTable('#employees', {
  info: false,
  paging: true,
  "aLengthMenu": [5, 10, 20],
  // "dom": 'rtip',
});
.dt-column-order:before {
  margin-bottom: 1px;
}

th {
  outline: none !important;
}

.dt-paging {
  margin-top: 15px !important;
}

.pagination {
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

/* CSS row count */
table {
  counter-reset: row-num;
}

table tbody tr {
  counter-increment: row-num;
}

table tbody tr td:first-child::before {
  content: counter(row-num) "";
}
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.7.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/2.1.8/js/dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/2.1.8/js/dataTables.bootstrap5.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/2.1.8/css/dataTables.bootstrap5.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container-fluid my-2">
  <h2>Data Tables</h2>
  <table id="employees" class="table table-bordered table-striped mx-1">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th data-dt-order="disable">No</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Position</th>
        <th>Office</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Start date</th>
        <th>Salary</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
        <td>System Architect</td>
        <td>Edinburgh</td>
        <td>61</td>
        <td>2011-04-25</td>
        <td>$320,800</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Garrett Winters</td>
        <td>Accountant</td>
        <td>Tokyo</td>
        <td>63</td>
        <td>2011-07-25</td>
        <td>$170,750</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Ashton Cox</td>
        <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>66</td>
        <td>2009-01-12</td>
        <td>$86,000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
        <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
        <td>Edinburgh</td>
        <td>22</td>
        <td>2012-03-29</td>
        <td>$433,060</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Ștefan Popa</td>
        <td>Accountant</td>
        <td>Tokyo</td>
        <td>33</td>
        <td>2008-11-28</td>
        <td>$162,700</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Brielle Williamson</td>
        <td>Integration Specialist</td>
        <td>New York</td>
        <td>61</td>
        <td>2012-12-02</td>
        <td>$372,000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Herrod Chandler</td>
        <td>Sales Assistant</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>59</td>
        <td>2012-08-06</td>
        <td>$137,500</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Rhona Davidson</td>
        <td>Integration Specialist</td>
        <td>Tokyo</td>
        <td>55</td>
        <td>2010-10-14</td>
        <td>$327,900</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Colleen Hurst</td>
        <td>Javascript Developer</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>39</td>
        <td>2009-09-15</td>
        <td>$205,500</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Sonya Frost</td>
        <td>Software Engineer</td>
        <td>Edinburgh</td>
        <td>23</td>
        <td>2008-12-13</td>
        <td>$103,600</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Jena Gaines</td>
        <td>Office Manager</td>
        <td>London</td>
        <td>30</td>
        <td>2008-12-19</td>
        <td>$90,560</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Quinn Flynn</td>
        <td>Support Lead</td>
        <td>Edinburgh</td>
        <td>22</td>
        <td>2013-03-03</td>
        <td>$342,000</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>



There is a problem with this solution though: whenever the results set is big enough so that there is pagination, the row count starts at 1 for every page.
So, I actually need a row count based on JavaScript, which would not reset the count for every page. I did not find a way to do this bult into DataTables.
Questions

Is there a built-in DataTables solution to this?
If not, what would be a viable solution to the problem?


"is there a built in solution" https://datatables.net/reference/api/row().index()

"is there an alternative solution" Offset by ([current page] - 1) * [page size]): https://datatables.net/reference/api/page.info()

@fdomn-m I am not trying to alert (or do anything else with) the row index on click. Only to relace the CSS-based row-count with a  JavaScript-based row-count.

Pretty sure it can be used for more than just the basic example they give in the documentation!

Use the render callback - this passes in the metadata for the current row, which includes the row index.    https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render

You might listen to draw event and update your CSS counter with the page.info().start number:


const table = new DataTable('#employees', {
  info: false,
  paging: true,
  "aLengthMenu": [5, 10, 20],
  // "dom": 'rtip',
});

table.on('draw', () => table.table().node().style.setProperty('--n', table.page.info().start));
.dt-column-order:before {
  margin-bottom: 1px;
}

th {
  outline: none !important;
}

.dt-paging {
  margin-top: 15px !important;
}

.pagination {
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

/* CSS row count */
table {
  --n: 0;
  counter-reset: row-num var(--n);
}

table tbody tr {
  counter-increment: row-num;
}

table tbody tr td:first-child::before {
  content: counter(row-num) "";
}
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.7.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/2.1.8/js/dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/2.1.8/js/dataTables.bootstrap5.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/2.1.8/css/dataTables.bootstrap5.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container-fluid my-2">
  <h2>Data Tables</h2>
  <table id="employees" class="table table-bordered table-striped mx-1">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th data-dt-order="disable">No</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Position</th>
        <th>Office</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Start date</th>
        <th>Salary</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
        <td>System Architect</td>
        <td>Edinburgh</td>
        <td>61</td>
        <td>2011-04-25</td>
        <td>$320,800</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Garrett Winters</td>
        <td>Accountant</td>
        <td>Tokyo</td>
        <td>63</td>
        <td>2011-07-25</td>
        <td>$170,750</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Ashton Cox</td>
        <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>66</td>
        <td>2009-01-12</td>
        <td>$86,000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
        <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
        <td>Edinburgh</td>
        <td>22</td>
        <td>2012-03-29</td>
        <td>$433,060</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Ștefan Popa</td>
        <td>Accountant</td>
        <td>Tokyo</td>
        <td>33</td>
        <td>2008-11-28</td>
        <td>$162,700</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Brielle Williamson</td>
        <td>Integration Specialist</td>
        <td>New York</td>
        <td>61</td>
        <td>2012-12-02</td>
        <td>$372,000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Herrod Chandler</td>
        <td>Sales Assistant</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>59</td>
        <td>2012-08-06</td>
        <td>$137,500</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Rhona Davidson</td>
        <td>Integration Specialist</td>
        <td>Tokyo</td>
        <td>55</td>
        <td>2010-10-14</td>
        <td>$327,900</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Colleen Hurst</td>
        <td>Javascript Developer</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>39</td>
        <td>2009-09-15</td>
        <td>$205,500</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Sonya Frost</td>
        <td>Software Engineer</td>
        <td>Edinburgh</td>
        <td>23</td>
        <td>2008-12-13</td>
        <td>$103,600</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Jena Gaines</td>
        <td>Office Manager</td>
        <td>London</td>
        <td>30</td>
        <td>2008-12-19</td>
        <td>$90,560</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Quinn Flynn</td>
        <td>Support Lead</td>
        <td>Edinburgh</td>
        <td>22</td>
        <td>2013-03-03</td>
        <td>$342,000</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>




In the example an event listener was added to document because the   <table> and maybe elements higher up in the hierarchy were being destroyed and created. Anyways it was tricky trying to get the correct page but I got an index number by finding the <button> currently residing within <li class="active">. Now that the right index was correct I used an array with the 3 numbers that were the starting row numbers for each page. Finally, I got a CSS variable --start to change the value of counter-set which is also the second value of counter-reset assigned to <table>. So every time the page is changed that value changes from 0 to 5 and to 10.


new DataTable('#employees', {
  info: false,
  paging: true,
  "aLengthMenu": [5, 10, 20],
  // "dom": 'rtip',
});

document.addEventListener("click", adjCounters);

function adjCounters(e) {
  const clk = e.target;
  const sel = document.querySelector("#dt-length-0").value;

  if (clk.matches("button")) {
    const act = document.querySelector(".active .page-link")
    const len = Number(sel);
    const idx = Number(act.getAttribute("data-dt-idx"));
    const pgs = len * idx;

    const table = document.querySelector("table");
    table.style.setProperty("--start", pgs);
  }
}
:root {
  --start: 0
}

.dt-layout-full {
  padding: 0 !important;
}

.dt-column-order:before {
  margin-bottom: 1px;
}

th {
  outline: none !important;
}

.dt-paging {
  margin-top: 15px !important;
}

.pagination {
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

/* CSS row count */
table {
  counter-reset: row-num var(--start)
}

table tbody tr {
  counter-increment: row-num;
}

table tbody tr td:first-child::before {
  content: counter(row-num) "";
}
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.7.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/2.1.8/js/dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/2.1.8/js/dataTables.bootstrap5.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/2.1.8/css/dataTables.bootstrap5.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container-fluid my-2">
  <h2>Data Tables</h2>
  <table id="employees" class="table table-bordered table-striped mx-1">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th data-dt-order="disable">No</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Position</th>
        <th>Office</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Start date</th>
        <th>Salary</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
        <td>System Architect</td>
        <td>Edinburgh</td>
        <td>61</td>
        <td>2011-04-25</td>
        <td>$320,800</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Garrett Winters</td>
        <td>Accountant</td>
        <td>Tokyo</td>
        <td>63</td>
        <td>2011-07-25</td>
        <td>$170,750</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Ashton Cox</td>
        <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>66</td>
        <td>2009-01-12</td>
        <td>$86,000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
        <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
        <td>Edinburgh</td>
        <td>22</td>
        <td>2012-03-29</td>
        <td>$433,060</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Ștefan Popa</td>
        <td>Accountant</td>
        <td>Tokyo</td>
        <td>33</td>
        <td>2008-11-28</td>
        <td>$162,700</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Brielle Williamson</td>
        <td>Integration Specialist</td>
        <td>New York</td>
        <td>61</td>
        <td>2012-12-02</td>
        <td>$372,000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Herrod Chandler</td>
        <td>Sales Assistant</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>59</td>
        <td>2012-08-06</td>
        <td>$137,500</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Rhona Davidson</td>
        <td>Integration Specialist</td>
        <td>Tokyo</td>
        <td>55</td>
        <td>2010-10-14</td>
        <td>$327,900</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Colleen Hurst</td>
        <td>Javascript Developer</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>39</td>
        <td>2009-09-15</td>
        <td>$205,500</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Sonya Frost</td>
        <td>Software Engineer</td>
        <td>Edinburgh</td>
        <td>23</td>
        <td>2008-12-13</td>
        <td>$103,600</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Jena Gaines</td>
        <td>Office Manager</td>
        <td>London</td>
        <td>30</td>
        <td>2008-12-19</td>
        <td>$90,560</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Quinn Flynn</td>
        <td>Support Lead</td>
        <td>Edinburgh</td>
        <td>22</td>
        <td>2013-03-03</td>
        <td>$342,000</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>




Great try, but there is one problem: if you change the number of entries per page, the row count is wrong. So it seems.

Ok now it'll adapt to the <select>  value and the current page index. Now you can add as many rows that you want.

Sorry, it is buggy...

How so? What browser and os are you using?

Chrome on Windows.

Me too and it works fine for me. Can you please elaborate on how exactly is it buggy?

Run the snippet, go to page 2 and then change the entries per page. Anyway, there should a bult-in reliable solution... :)

Ah, OK, I delegated the "click" event to the <select> it should work now.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

"Is there a built-in DataTables solution to this?"
Yes there is, assuming I have understood what you mean by "row count" in your question.
I assume you don't mean "a count of the total number of rows"... But rather the row number, starting at "1" for your "Tiger Nixon" row, and "2" for the next row, and so on... And that number needs to be independent of sorting, filtering, and pagination: the "Tiger Nixon" row should always be row number "1" in the first column of the table, even when it is not displayed as the very first row seen by a user, due to sorting/filtering/pagination.

Every row is allocated an index number, based on the order in which the data is first loaded into the DataTable when the DataTable is initialized. That assigned index number never changes, unless you delete data from the DataTable or re-initialize the DataTable.
This index number is accessed via the DataTables API using row().index().
More usefully, in your case, the row index can be accessed by a column data function: function data( row, type, set, meta ), which is documented on this page.
See the definition for the meta parameter in that function. It gives you access to:

"the row index for the requested cell"


So, your demo can use meta as follows:


<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Demo</title>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.7.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/2.1.8/js/dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/2.1.8/js/dataTables.bootstrap5.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/2.1.8/css/dataTables.bootstrap5.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container-fluid my-2">
    <h2>Data Tables</h2>
    <table id="employees" class="table table-bordered table-striped mx-1">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th data-dt-order="disable">No</th>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Position</th>
          <th>Office</th>
          <th>Age</th>
          <th>Start date</th>
          <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
          <td>System Architect</td>
          <td>Edinburgh</td>
          <td>61</td>
          <td>2011-04-25</td>
          <td>$320,800</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td>Garrett Winters</td>
          <td>Accountant</td>
          <td>Tokyo</td>
          <td>63</td>
          <td>2011-07-25</td>
          <td>$170,750</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td>Ashton Cox</td>
          <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
          <td>San Francisco</td>
          <td>66</td>
          <td>2009-01-12</td>
          <td>$86,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
          <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
          <td>Edinburgh</td>
          <td>22</td>
          <td>2012-03-29</td>
          <td>$433,060</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td>Ștefan Popa</td>
          <td>Accountant</td>
          <td>Tokyo</td>
          <td>33</td>
          <td>2008-11-28</td>
          <td>$162,700</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td>Brielle Williamson</td>
          <td>Integration Specialist</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>61</td>
          <td>2012-12-02</td>
          <td>$372,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td>Herrod Chandler</td>
          <td>Sales Assistant</td>
          <td>San Francisco</td>
          <td>59</td>
          <td>2012-08-06</td>
          <td>$137,500</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td>Rhona Davidson</td>
          <td>Integration Specialist</td>
          <td>Tokyo</td>
          <td>55</td>
          <td>2010-10-14</td>
          <td>$327,900</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td>Colleen Hurst</td>
          <td>Javascript Developer</td>
          <td>San Francisco</td>
          <td>39</td>
          <td>2009-09-15</td>
          <td>$205,500</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td>Sonya Frost</td>
          <td>Software Engineer</td>
          <td>Edinburgh</td>
          <td>23</td>
          <td>2008-12-13</td>
          <td>$103,600</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td>Jena Gaines</td>
          <td>Office Manager</td>
          <td>London</td>
          <td>30</td>
          <td>2008-12-19</td>
          <td>$90,560</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td>Quinn Flynn</td>
          <td>Support Lead</td>
          <td>Edinburgh</td>
          <td>22</td>
          <td>2013-03-03</td>
          <td>$342,000</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>

  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

      new DataTable('#employees', {
        info: false,
        paging: true,
        "aLengthMenu": [5, 10, 20],
        // "dom": 'rtip',
        columnDefs: [{
          targets: [0],
          data: function(row, type, val, meta) {
            if (meta) {
              return meta.row + 1;
            } else {
              return null;
            }
          }
        }]
      });

    });
  </script>

</body>

</html>



This has the advantage that you are operating directly on the DataTables data - and not on the data which happens to be displayed in the DOM for a given page of visible data.

Why is that if (meta) needed? Because of DataTables' support for orthogonal data, which allows you to store different values for a cell, for different purposes (what you see in a cell may be different from how you want to sort or filter that data).
There is one extra orthogonal type (set - used by plugins) which does not contain any meta data - so your code would throw an error (meta does not exist) without this check.

Option 2
Alternatively...
For static row numbers (similar to Excel), then you need to re-write the display data every time the user performs a sort, filter or pagination action.
That does involve some JavaScript, using the DataTables API.
First, define a table variable, and also add an initComplete function, to handle the very first time the table is displayed:
var table = new DataTable('#employees', {
  info: false,
  paging: true,
  "aLengthMenu": [5, 10, 20],
  // "dom": 'rtip',
  initComplete: function() {
    writeRowNumbers();
  }
});

Add an on draw event, to handle all subsequent changes made by the user (sort/filter/paginate):
table.on( 'draw', function () {
  writeRowNumbers()
} );

The row numbers writer is straightforward - it just iterates over the visible (DOM) data in the displayed table:
function writeRowNumbers() {
  $('#employees tbody tr').each(function( index ) {
    $('td', this ).first().html(index + 1);
  } );
}

But again, maybe I have failed to understand what you mean by "row count"...

Option 3
This last option is for future visitors to the site, who may be interested in different approaches.
This is a variation on option 2, but instead of starting each new page of results at "1", this takes the currently displayed page number into account.
It uses page.info().start to get the:

"display index for the first record shown on the current page"

Because rows are zero-indexed, we add 1 to start, in the code below.
var table = new DataTable('#employees', {
  info: false,
  paging: true,
  "aLengthMenu": [5, 10, 20],
  // "dom": 'rtip',
  initComplete: function() {
    writeRowNumbers(1); // hard-coded 1 for the initial display
  }
});

table.on( 'draw', function () {
  writeRowNumbers(table.page.info().start +1)
} );

function writeRowNumbers(offset) {
  $('#employees tbody tr').each(function( index ) {
    $('td', this ).first().html(index + offset);
  } );
}

A runnable demo of option 3:


<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Demo</title>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.7.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/2.1.8/js/dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/2.1.8/js/dataTables.bootstrap5.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/2.1.8/css/dataTables.bootstrap5.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container-fluid my-2">
    <h2>Data Tables</h2>
    <table id="employees" class="table table-bordered table-striped mx-1">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th data-dt-order="disable">No</th>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Position</th>
          <th>Office</th>
          <th>Age</th>
          <th>Start date</th>
          <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
          <td>System Architect</td>
          <td>Edinburgh</td>
          <td>61</td>
          <td>2011-04-25</td>
          <td>$320,800</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td>Garrett Winters</td>
          <td>Accountant</td>
          <td>Tokyo</td>
          <td>63</td>
          <td>2011-07-25</td>
          <td>$170,750</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td>Ashton Cox</td>
          <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
          <td>San Francisco</td>
          <td>66</td>
          <td>2009-01-12</td>
          <td>$86,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
          <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
          <td>Edinburgh</td>
          <td>22</td>
          <td>2012-03-29</td>
          <td>$433,060</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td>Ștefan Popa</td>
          <td>Accountant</td>
          <td>Tokyo</td>
          <td>33</td>
          <td>2008-11-28</td>
          <td>$162,700</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td>Brielle Williamson</td>
          <td>Integration Specialist</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>61</td>
          <td>2012-12-02</td>
          <td>$372,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td>Herrod Chandler</td>
          <td>Sales Assistant</td>
          <td>San Francisco</td>
          <td>59</td>
          <td>2012-08-06</td>
          <td>$137,500</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td>Rhona Davidson</td>
          <td>Integration Specialist</td>
          <td>Tokyo</td>
          <td>55</td>
          <td>2010-10-14</td>
          <td>$327,900</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td>Colleen Hurst</td>
          <td>Javascript Developer</td>
          <td>San Francisco</td>
          <td>39</td>
          <td>2009-09-15</td>
          <td>$205,500</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td>Sonya Frost</td>
          <td>Software Engineer</td>
          <td>Edinburgh</td>
          <td>23</td>
          <td>2008-12-13</td>
          <td>$103,600</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td>Jena Gaines</td>
          <td>Office Manager</td>
          <td>London</td>
          <td>30</td>
          <td>2008-12-19</td>
          <td>$90,560</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td>Quinn Flynn</td>
          <td>Support Lead</td>
          <td>Edinburgh</td>
          <td>22</td>
          <td>2013-03-03</td>
          <td>$342,000</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>

  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

      var table = new DataTable('#employees', {
        info: false,
        paging: true,
        "aLengthMenu": [5, 10, 20],
        // "dom": 'rtip',
        initComplete: function() {
          writeRowNumbers(1);
        }
      });

      table.on('draw', function() {
        writeRowNumbers(table.page.info().start + 1)
      });

      function writeRowNumbers(offset) {
        $('#employees tbody tr').each(function(index) {
          $('td', this).first().html(index + offset);
        });
      }

    });
  </script>

</body>

</html>




Great code, but if I (re)order the the rows by name (or any other column), the row count gets messed-up.

In that case, I don't know what you mean by "row count". I provided my understanding of what I thought you meant in my answer, but clearly that is not what you mean. You can edit your question to clarify: Show us an example of what you expect to see when it is working the way you want it to work.

The only other thing I can guess you need is a row order similar to how something like Excel works - where the first row a user sees is always "row 1", regardless of sorting/filtering/pagination. That, also can be done using DataTables. If that is what you actually need...

Yes, That is what I am looking for. Or, as I have mentioned at the end, "a row count based on JavaScript, which would not reset the count for every page".

OK - I did add more notes to my answer, already. But I have to confess I don't know what you mean by "not reset the count for every page". Anyway, I hope that one of the various approaches in the answers do give you what you need.

I agree with @andrewJames you are not clear as to what you want. I thought you wanted each row to be number regardless of which page being viewed. So that would be rows 1 to 12  on  1 page set at 20,  rows 1 to 12 on 2 pages set at 10 and rows 1 - 12 on 3 pages set at 5.  You say "...which would not reset the count for every page" That's what my answer does.
